# Use of would had been

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Read below the sentences

> My wish would had completed.
>
> If I would had been to London.

Are they grammatically correct? What's the use of "would had" in them?

Do both the following sentences mean the same thing?

> If I would had been the president.
>
> If I were the president.

I've been learning English Grammar recently, So as a new comer I'm having these doubts. Could someone please help me? I've searched everything from the web, but the information was unavailable.

Comment: Try 'would **have**'

Answer (score 2):

The construction **would had** doesn't exist in English. If you are talking about something that you might do in certain circumstances, you would say:

> I would go (if I had the time).

If you are talking about something that you might have done in the past under certain circumstances, you would say:

> I would have gone (if I'd had the time).

Neither **If I would had been president** nor **If I would have been president** is correct.

To say:

> If I had been president

is to reflect on what might have happened in the past if you had occupied the position of president.

To say:

> If I were president

is to reflect on what you might do or say in the event that you became president.

Answer (score 0):

First, modal auxiliaries like *would* are **always** followed by the base form of the verb, not by a past or past participle, so *would had* is never grammatical, (in any variety of English, as far as I know). You mean *would have*, as Kate Bunting said in a comment.

Second, using *would* in a condition (eg "If I would have") is grammatical in some varieties of English, but not as far as I know in any standard varieties: I would never say it, but many people do so nowadays.

Thirdly, *would have* is a sort of past modal, so *If I would have been the president* is a non-standard version of *If I had been the president* (past counterfactual). The present counterfactual equivalents are (standard) *If I were the president*, (non-standard) *If I would be the president*.

You first sentence is not a conditional, so its form would be grammatical if you change *had* to *have*; but there are other problems with it: *completed* is active, so it is not something that a wish can normally do; and in any case it is not the usual verb for what happens to wishes. I suspect you meant *My wish would have been granted* (or *carried out*).